# A list of active views in prism

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, prism, mef

Doez prism assign any unique identifier/guid maintained for each view ?

Perhaps in tracking any references etc?

Comment: Prism does not track active views itself; each region tracks the views it hosts independently. But the question is pretty unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prism doesn't do it. But you can do it easily if needed. However, I learned that you don't need to do this if you properly use navigation and navigation parameters.